# npm and node installed by opkg get Segmentation fault error

Tags: node.js, qnap, opkg

I try to install npm and node in my qnap nas TS-416.And I used opkg to install them.I installed successfully but I can't run them as they return 'Segmentation fault'

```
[/share/archivebox] # opkg install node-npm
Installing node-npm (v18.17.1-1) to root...
Downloading http://bin.entware.net/aarch64-k3.10/node-npm_v18.17.1-1_aarch64-3.10.ipk
Installing node (v18.17.1-1) to root...
Downloading http://bin.entware.net/aarch64-k3.10/node_v18.17.1-1_aarch64-3.10.ipk

Configuring node.
Configuring node-npm.
[/share/archivebox] # npm
Segmentation fault
[/share/archivebox] # node
Segmentation fault
```

By the way,how can I install old version of node by opkg?

I tried download from web,now I can run node but still get 'Segmentation fault' when running npm

```
[/share/archivebox/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64] # wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64.tar.gz
[/share/archivebox] # tar -xf node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64.tar.gz
[/share/archivebox] # cd node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64
[/share/archivebox/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64] # bin/node
Welcome to Node.js v16.20.2.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
(To exit, press Ctrl+C again or Ctrl+D or type .exit)
>
[/share/archivebox/node-v16.20.2-linux-arm64] # bin/npm
Segmentation fault
```